# How to build OpenLDAP in windows and get binaries?

Tags: ldap, openldap

How can i get binaries for these tools: [ldapadd ldapcompare ldapdelete ldapexop ldapmodify ldapmodrdn ldappasswd ldapsearch ldapurl ldapvc ldapwhoami]

I tried to build openLDAP version 2.6.3 from here: https://www.openldap.org/software/download/ in windows but i couldn't manage it then i get build it in Kali Linux and using these commands from this webpage https://www.openldap.org/software/release/install.html:

```
./configure
make depend
make
make install
```

but i still not getting binaries. Hase anyone tips or experience and can me support.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openldap version 2.6.3 is vorhanden as package in cygwin Environment
so one can install cygwin from https://www.cygwin.com/install.html and during installation choose view: Full, search: openldap and check openldap package:
This will install these tools [ldapadd ldapcompare ldapdelete ldapexop ldapmodify ldapmodrdn ldappasswd ldapsearch ldapurl ldapvc ldapwhoami]

under c:\cygwin\bin